# GSON + parse json from webservice and get the json string for the particular JsonObject

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a scenario where I read json from webservice. This Json is an array of nodes which has a lot of data

What I want to achieve:

1. For each Node in the array, read only required elements. Done this using GSON object model.
2. For each Node in the array, need the Json String for that particular node and add it to the Java Object from step 1 as String.

Step 2 is required as Java impl will call another service which in turn needs the json for each node for further processing.

What I tried in order to achieve this:

1. Create java object using object model for step 1.
2. Read the whole json again using Object model with JsonArray.class, which gives me the Json string for each node (JsonArray.get(i).toString()).
3. Find a way to match the Json String and Java object, may be using Node id, which again needs from parsing from Step 2.

My questions:

1. Am I using the right approach? Is parsing the Json two times alright? Are there any better ways to achieve this?
2. I was not keen using JsonReader, but would that be a better solution? if so how to justify?

staff.json:

```
[
{
    "name": "Joe",
    "age" : 35,
    "position": "dev",
    "salary": 10000,
    "skills":[ "angular", "aws", "java"],
    "Organistaion" : "Test",
    "WorkType": "Full-time"
},

{
    "name": "John",
    "age" : 29,
    "position": "dev",
    "salary": 10000,
    "skills":[ "python", "c#", "java"],
    "Organistaion" : "Test",
    "WorkType": "Full-time"
}
```

]

Staff.java:

```
public class Staff {
private String name;
private int age;
private String staffJson;
.......
```

}

StaffSandbox.java:

```
public class StaffSandbox {
public static void main (String s[]) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader("C:\\staff.json")) { // for sample code use file

        // Step 1
        List<Staff> staffs = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Staff>>() {}.getType());
        staffs.forEach(System.out::println);

        // Step 2
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(("C:\\staff.json"))));
        JsonArray jsonElement = gson.fromJson(json, JsonArray.class);
        System.out.println( gson.toJson(jsonElement.get(0)).toString());

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 0; i < json.size(); i++) {
            // Read the node Id and match with corresponding Staff object and add the json to it            
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Am I using the right approach? Is parsing the Json two times alright? Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Not really. You can avoid reading the file two times + save a lot of memory in *your* second read: you're reading entire file to a byte array first converting to a string converting to a JSON array. Test this approach for huge files, and you'll probably have `OutOfMemoryError`.

> I was not keen using JsonReader, but would that be a better solution? if so how to justify?

`JsonReader` works in streaming manner tokenizing JSON input, and it can help you a lot in many and many cases.

If I understood you correctly, you just need something like this:

```java
private static void zip(final Gson gson, final Reader reader, final Consumer<? super JsonObject> consumer)
        throws IOException {
    // The next two lines request some stuff from the given Gson instance
    final TypeAdapter<JsonObject> jsonObjectTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonObject.class);
    final JsonReader jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(reader);
    // Ensure that the very first token is array begin `[`
    jsonReader.beginArray();
    // And read all the array elements
    while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
        // JsonReader does not consume entire input stream and can read necessary JSON token only
        final JsonObject incomingJsonObject = jsonObjectTypeAdapter.read(jsonReader);
        // And this is what we generate
        final JsonObject outgoingJsonObject = new JsonObject();
        outgoingJsonObject.add("name", incomingJsonObject.get("name"));
        outgoingJsonObject.add("age", incomingJsonObject.get("age"));
        outgoingJsonObject.add("staffJson", new JsonPrimitive(incomingJsonObject.toString()));
        // Once a "staff row" is ready to use, just delegate it elsewhere
        consumer.accept(outgoingJsonObject);
    }
    jsonReader.endArray();
}
```

Note that the example above does not use Java mappings like what your `Staff` is. If you need it, you can convert a `JsonElement` to a Java mapping and vice versa with `Gson.toJsonTree()` and `Gson.fromJson()`. Moreover, you can even write the output directly to a specified `JsonWriter` not even creating `outgoingJsonObject` instances (trivial R/W pipe: read from input ==> process ==> write to output).

Example of use (note that the `Reader` cannot be used twice or more; consumer implementations use different strategies: flush each newly generated `JsonObject` directly to `System.out` (you can process very huge data sets like that); or collect all such objects to a list and then do whatever you want (a collection must fit in memory)):

```java
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43105667.class, "staff.json") ) {
    zip(gson, reader, System.out::println);
}
try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43105667.class, "staff.json") ) {
    final Collection<JsonObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    zip(gson, reader, list::add);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

> {"name":"Joe","age":35,"staffJson":"{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":35,\"position\":\"dev\",\"salary\":10000,\"skills\":[\"angular\",\"aws\",\"java\"],\"Organistaion\":\"Test\",\"WorkType\":\"Full-time\"}"}
>   {"name":"John","age":29,"staffJson":"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":29,\"position\":\"dev\",\"salary\":10000,\"skills\":[\"python\",\"c#\",\"java\"],\"Organistaion\":\"Test\",\"WorkType\":\"Full-time\"}"}
>   [{"name":"Joe","age":35,"staffJson":"{\"name\":\"Joe\",\"age\":35,\"position\":\"dev\",\"salary\":10000,\"skills\":[\"angular\",\"aws\",\"java\"],\"Organistaion\":\"Test\",\"WorkType\":\"Full-time\"}"}, {"name":"John","age":29,"staffJson":"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":29,\"position\":\"dev\",\"salary\":10000,\"skills\":[\"python\",\"c#\",\"java\"],\"Organistaion\":\"Test\",\"WorkType\":\"Full-time\"}"}]